# How can I subscribe joint_controller/state from dynamixel

Tags: ros, dynamixel-controller, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I write the following code to subscribe . How can I get the current pos data.

```
import rospy
from dynamixel_msgs import JointState


def callback(data):
    print "callback"
    print data


def listener():
    rospy.init_node('starter', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("/joint6_controller/state", current_pos, callback)
    rospy.spin()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88076/how-can-i-subscribe-joint_controller/state-from-dynamixel/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the callback

```
current_position = data.current_pos
```

should do the trick.
Also note, that this:

```
rospy.Subscriber("/joint6_controller/state", current_pos, callback)
```

should be this:

```
rospy.Subscriber("/joint6_controller/state", JointState, callback)
```

The dynamixel controller Joint State message documentation is [here](http://docs.ros.org/api/dynamixel_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html). If you want to access any other member, just call "data.[member name goes here]".

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [jdorich](https://answers.ros.org/users/7496/jdorich/) with karma: 211 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0